# Selecting the child term first while using 'Hierarchical' Select module

Tags: navigation, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy category in the following hierarchy: Country->State->City.

Now, I have a field in one of my content types which uses the Hierarchical Select module. In the front end, users are supposed to chose the Country, based on which the states corresponding to the selected Country are auto-filled. City list is auto-filled based on the selected State.

Now, is it possible for me to allow users to select City first and then autofill the Country and State fields based on the selected city? Basically, is there a way to first select the child term, and then based on that selected chose the parent term?

Comment: What you probably need is to use[cshs](https://www.drupal.org/project/cshs)

Comment: Well, I already mentioned that I'm using this very module for implementing this use case.

Comment: Sorry -  Alternative I can think of is https://www.drupal.org/project/cshs - I believe it forces selection from deepest level. If that works for you, will amend my answer.

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi Your question doesn't mention that module at all. cshs != hierarchical_select, they're different things